# How to remove white space coming after text and before a title?

Tags: spacing

I have white space in the first column of my page and I would like to remove thlis white space and have the title displayed instead 
[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcommand{\mh}[1]{
  {\color{green!70!black} MH: #1}}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}

\begin{document}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\setcopyright{none}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}
\pagestyle{plain}
%%
%% This command processes the author and affiliation and title
%% information and builds the first part of the formatted document.
\maketitle
\begin{table*}[]
\caption{Precision/recall and completeness of the requirement-to-method traces output by our approach}
\label{Results}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1-\\ Prog.\end{tabular}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2-\\ Step\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Cumulative Predictions}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cunulative Output\\  Completeness\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Cumulative Precision and Recall}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulaltive \\ Output \\ Precision\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative\\ Output\\ Recall\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{3-18} 
 &  & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3-\\ T\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-\\ N\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}5-\\ U\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-\\ Total\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}7-\\ T\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}8-\\ N\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}9-\\ U\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}10-\\ TP\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}11-\\ TN\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12-\\ FP\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}13-\\ FN\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}14-\\ U\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}15-\\ T\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}16-\\ N\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}17-\\ T\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}18-\\ N\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Chess}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 2063 & 3953 & 6016 & 0.00 & 34.29 & 65.71 & 0 & 1612 & 0 & 0 & 4404 & NA & 100 & NA & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{2} & 0 & 3144 & 2872 & 6016 & 0.00 & 52.26 & 47.74 & 0 & 1822 & 0 & 46 & 4148 & NA & 97.54 & 0.00 & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{3} & 923 & 3144 & 1949 & 6016 & 15.34 & 52.26 & 32.40 & 417 & 1822 & 391 & 46 & 3340 & 51.61 & 97.54 & 90.06 & 82.33 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1403} & \textbf{3144} & \textbf{1469} & \textbf{6016} & \textbf{24.32} & \textbf{52.26} & \textbf{24.42} & \textbf{467} & \textbf{1822} & \textbf{448} & \textbf{46} & \textbf{3233} & \textbf{51.04} & \textbf{97.54} & \textbf{91.03} & \textbf{80.26} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Gantt}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 55535 & 34699 & 90234 & 0.00 & 61.55 & 38.45 & 0 & 22365 & 0 & 0 & 67869 & NA & 100 & NA & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{2} & 0 & 66609 & 23625 & 90234 & 0.00 & 73.49 & 26.51 & 0 & 22592 & 0 & 57 & 67582 & NA & 99.75 & 0.00 & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{3} & 908 & 66609 & 228729 & 90234 & 1.01 & 73.49 & 25.50 & 97 & 22592 & 124 & 57 & 67364 & 43.89 & 99.75 & 62.99 & 99.45 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1527} & \textbf{66609} & \textbf{22098} & \textbf{90234} & \textbf{1.70} & \textbf{73.49} & \textbf{24.81} & \textbf{146} & \textbf{22592} & \textbf{184} & \textbf{57} & \textbf{64255} & \textbf{44.24} & \textbf{99.75} & \textbf{71.92} & \textbf{99.19} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{iTrust}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 17573 & 149469 & 166838 & 0.00 & 10.52 & 89.48 & 0 & 6572 & 0 & 0 & 160470 & NA & 100 & NA & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{2} & 0 & 28657 & 138385 & 166838 & 0.00 & 17.16 & 82.84 & 0 & 6685 & 0 & 9 & 160348 & NA & 99.87 & 0.00 & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{3} & 290 & 28657 & 138095 & 166838 & 0.17 & 17.16 & 82.67 & 81 & 6685 & 27 & 9 & 160240 & 75.00 & 99.87 & 90.00 & 99.60 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1527} & \textbf{28657} & \textbf{137350} & \textbf{166838} & \textbf{0.62} & \textbf{17.16} & \textbf{82.22} & \textbf{93} & \textbf{6685} & \textbf{28} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{160227} & \textbf{76.86} & \textbf{99.87} & \textbf{91.18} & \textbf{99.58} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}JHot\\ Draw\end{tabular}}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 116787 & 20133 & 136920 & 0.00 & 85.30 & 14.70 & 0 & 12013 & 0 & 0 & 124907 & NA & 100 & NA & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{2} & 0 & 125748 & 11172 & 136920 & 0.00 & 91.84 & 8.16 & 0 & 12066 & 0 & 86 & 124768 & NA & 99.29 & 0.00 & 100.00 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{3} & 1738 & 125748 & 9434 & 136920 & 1.27 & 91.84 & 6.89 & 98 & 12066 & 34 & 86 & 124636 & 74.24 & 99.29 & 53.26 & 99.72 \\ \cline{2-18} 
 & \textbf{4} & \textbf{2389} & \textbf{125748} & \textbf{8783} & \textbf{136920} & \textbf{1.74} & \textbf{91.84} & \textbf{6.41} & \textbf{132} & \textbf{12066} & \textbf{49} & \textbf{86} & \textbf{124587} & \textbf{72.93} & \textbf{99.29} & \textbf{60.55} & \textbf{99.60} \\ \hline
\textbf{Avg} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1589} & \textbf{56040} & \textbf{42425} & \textbf{100002} & \textbf{6.98} & \textbf{58.69} & \textbf{34.47} & \textbf{210} & \textbf{10791} & \textbf{177} & \textbf{50} & \textbf{88076} & \textbf{61.27} & \textbf{99.11} & \textbf{78.67} & \textbf{64.66} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table*}
predictions in the case of JHotDraw). Indeed, No Trace precision is between 97-99\% for each program at the end of step 4. High precision is meaningless if recall is low. This is discussed next:
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
\item{\textit{Trace recall = TP/(TP+FN): represents the fraction of relevant Traces.}}
\item{\textit{No Trace recall = TN/(TN+FP): represents the fraction of relevant No Traces.}}
\end{itemize}
We notice in table~\ref{Results} that Trace Recall is 61-91\% and No Trace recall is 80-99\% (indeed 99\% for all systems except the small Chess). Trace Recall is particularly important here because any Traces incorrectly predicted as No Traces require software engineers to investigate the rather large set of No Trace predictions to find them. With a recall in average around 80\%, most traces are indeed found by our approach or remain in the gray zone of undefined traces. Ideally, recall should be higher still and future work will investigate this. We believe that the false negatives (which are at fault here) are likely close to the true positives in the code structure. Since No Trace recall and No Trace precision are both very high (99.11\% and 94.66\% in average), this means that our approach is quite capable in identifying NoTrace predictions correctly and completely. Software engineers hence can thus trust the NoTrace predictions. Given that the No Trace predictions also cover the vast majority of the code, software engineers should merely need to focus their attention on the remaining code. Take, for example, our largest case study JHotDraw. Of its 136,920 comparable cells in its requirement- to-method RTM, 125,748 cells were predicted to contain No Traces with 99.3\% precision and 99.6\% recall. Hence, the much smaller, remaining number set of cells (the 2389 Traces and 8783 Undefined Traces) is a much more manageable subset for software engineers to focus on. This saves software engineers effort.
\subsection{Applicability and Generalization}
After demonstrating our approach’s benefits in terms of completeness and correctness, we also want to make a few, final observations about our approach’s applicability. \mh{added a line saying that our findings can be generalized to other applications}First and foremost, given the high number of LOC in our case studies and given that we are considering the key requirements of the systems specified by developers, we conjecture that our findings can be generalized to other applications. Also, the four case study systems were very diverse and built by different people. One system, iTrust, even included network communication which obscures method calls (i.e., no observable calls between client and server). Still, our approach delivered very good results. However, all case studies had Java in common. Hence, one might ask whether our approach is limited to Java only. Given that very little code structure is used as part of our approach's reasoning, we do not believe so. Methods and method calls are commonly found in non-Java/non-OO languages including C, Python, C\#, and many more. The implements/inherits constructs are also not limited to Java. However, they are not a benefit but a complexity in this paper. If a language does not have interface/implementation construct concepts then our approach does not need to have an extended caller/callee that guesses their effect. The same can be said about inheritance. The extended caller/callee is thus an optional part of our algorithm. Therefore, overall, we see no major limitation in applying our approach to other languages and future work will do so.
\subsection{Precision/Recall Comparison with Other Techniques}
\mh{added this subsection since reviewers were complaining that we did not discuss how our technique compares to others}
In order to evaluate the performance of our technique, we collected the precision and recall values obtained after applying other major 

\end{document}
```

Comment: latex (in accordance with centuries of tradition) will not make a column or page break immediately after a title, so there is not space to get a title and two lines of text in the first column

Comment: Please edit the example so that it produces the problem shown, if I run it with pdflatex the table comes on its own at the top of page 2, with all the text on page 1.  If you provided an example people could test possible solutions.

Comment: You may reduce the left margin of the bullet list so the first item only use one line. That may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The example does not generate the problem shown and I couldn't make it do so with a couple of changes I tried, so these suggestions are untested.

LaTeX will not break after a section heading (you could force that, but you shouldn't) so there are two possibilities:

- Reduce the text in the first column, so that the heading and a couple of lines of text fit at the bottom, or
- Increase the text in the first column, or reduce the column height so that the text ends at the bottom of the first column.

To achieve the first, you could

- make a change at any point in the text earlier in the document that would pull a couple of lines on to an earlier page, but restricting to the text visible in this example, you could (perhaps) re-word the two indented items (and reduce the indentation) so that they fit on one line.  That would save you two lines which is probably enough.
- You could also use `\looseness=-1` before the long final paragraph which would tell TeX to try to adjust the linebreaking to take one less line.

To achieve the second you could

- add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}` before the `tabular` to make the top float bigger. Your image shows about 4 lines difference in height so if you make the float 2 baselines bigger then it will naturally balance with each text column having two line less, or
- You could slightly increase the spacing around the itemised list to push the bottom of the first column down by a line or two.